# If $|f(x)|<x^2$ for $|x|<1$, then show that $f'(x) $ exists and find it

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I can intuitively guess the answer is 0

because if we graph of f(x) must be below x^2

looking for a clean and more logical attempt

Comment: Is the question about $f'(0)$?

Comment: I don't see how any function $f$ can satisfy the given condition.The condition implies that $|f(0)| < 0$, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Most likely, the question should be "If $|f(x)| \le x^2$ for $|x| < 1$, then show that $f'(0)$ exists and find it." If that is what the question should have said, the OP needs to correct it.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that $0 \le \left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right| = \dfrac{|f(x)|}{|x|} \le \dfrac{x^2}{|x|} = |x|$ for all $x$ such that $|x| < 1$ and $x \neq 0$.

What does this tell you about $f'(0) = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$?

---

Also, note that $f'(x)$ isn't guaranteed to exist anywhere other than $x = 0$.

Consider $f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 & x \ \text{is rational}\\-x^2 & x \ \text{is irrational}\end{cases}$. This function satisfies $|f(x)| \le x^2$ for $|x| < 1$, but isn't differentiable (or even continuous) anywhere except at $x = 0$.